# Is it possible to use WPF on unix?

Tags: c#, wpf, linux, unix, cross-platform

I heard about Mono project but only in regards to winforms. Will it work with WPF?

Comment: This question makes absolutely no sense. Unix is an operating system.

Comment: So... is it possible to rewrite Unix using WPF? We should try. You tackle device drivers, I'll handle the GUI.

Comment: I believe he means - does WPF work with unix? He has heard only of mono under unix with winforms and wants to get more information.

Comment: @dotalchemy: Haha. LINUX: Linux is NOT Unix. While it's true that the GUI isn't as polished as on BlueScreen32, it isn't as neglected as the Unix one. And appart from that, who needs a GUI anyway ? Everything is simpler, faster and more stable (not to mention less ressource needing) on the console. Only people who don't know what they do need a GUI. Did you ever see windows 2008 (+database +IIS) run on 48 MB RAM, serving 200 concurrent users? My Linux server does, and it's quite fast.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[WPF under Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/WPF) does not exist.

> At this point, no group in the Mono project has plans to implement Windows Presentation Foundation APIs as part of the project.

The mono team propose using Silverlight/Moonlight instead:

> Silverlight implement a subset of the WPF APIs and is available on Windows, MacOS X and through our own open source effort Moonlight it is available on Linux and other Unix systems.

Answer (score 1):

There is a library called [Silverform SDK](http://www.silverform.com) that aims to provide cross-platform WPF and Silverlight implementation.

The library is implemented in managed code and currently works with OpenTK and Unity3D as render backends. Major functionality, such as binding, layout, main controls and primitives, has already been implemented (check Unity web player demos [here](http://www.silverform.com/demonstration-page)). Initially it has been focused on Unity3d render, while support for standalone Mono applications will be added as a separate build in the future.

Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of the library.